# How can I use log4net inside .net 2.1 cod base

Tags: .net-core, log4net

I want to use log4net in my .net core 2.1 project but when I add it, it has a yellow exclamation triangle next to it and I get this message in the output window.

> warning NU1701: Package 'log4net 2.0.5' was restored using
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework
>   '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible
>   with your project.

Any idea how I can make the project happy using log4net? what will happen if I try and use it with the exclamation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade your `Log4net` to at least version `2.0.6` *(or higher)* as from this version it supports `.NET Standard 1.3` which allows `Log4net` to be used on `.NET Core`.

Note that not everything is supported on `.NET Core` (eg. `AdoNetAppender`, `SmtpAppender`) see the [release notes](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/framework-support.html).

Comment: Ahh perfect, thank you I thought I was using the latest but wasn't!